# What is the difference between spring-data-jpa Repository pattern Vs Querydsl query pattern?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, querydsl, jpa-2.1

I am devloping `Spring MVC + spring-data-jpa + Hibernate` example. I'm using simple `Repository` (by `extending JpaRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>`) pattern to perform querying on `DataSource(DS)` and get the result. Even I can write any custom query as per my business needs.

While doing research, I find the `"querydsl-sql"` API. This API uses plugins and need to use `QueryDslPredicateExecutor<T>` like (by

```
extending JpaRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>,
QueryDslPredicateExecutor<T>)
```

. But on high level it look to me that this API also does the same thing that `Repository` API does.

Could someone please suggest / guide what is the difference between two methods? One use simple Repository and another uses QueryDslPredicateExecutor

```
List<Customer> findByCustomerNumberAndCustomerId(Integer customerNumber, Integer customerId);
```

Querydsl method

```
    @Query("select c from Customer c where c.customerNumber=:customerNumber and c.customerId=:customerId")
    List<Customer> findByCustomerNumberAndCustomerId(@Param("customerNumber") 
Integer customerNumber, @Param("customerId") Integer customerId);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Querydsl method example is actually a spring-data repository method.

The difference is that QueryDsl offers a simple and beautiful way to create dynamic queries to database. I.e. it allows to create SQL "on the fly".
This is useful when for example you need to retrieve a collection of entities with a complex filter. E.g. by name, date, cost etc. And resulting SQL should contain only conditions which specified in filter.

Spring data allows to achieve this without Querydsl using built-in Specifications API but Querydsl way is simpler and even more IDE-friendly.

More on this:
https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/